# How to run Noise reduction filter from plug-in?

Tags: gimp, gimpfu

I want to write a plug-in, that besides other things, apply Enhance/Noise reduction filter. But I found out that there is no similar procedure in the browser. And even no documentation for this filter, which is strange.

So, does anybody knows how to call Noise reduction filter from a plugin? And why some of the filters not documented and not present in procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its icon indicates, this is a GEGL operation, and unfortunately these have currently no API for scripts.

To be more complete, and as far as I can tell:

- No new API has been added for the new GEGL tools
- However, for compatibility:

  - Functions that had an existing non-GEGL implementation have been converted to use the equivalent GEGL tool (for instance `deinterlace` and `blur-gauss` still are called `plug-in-something` in the API but you won't find them listed in `pluginrc`)
  - Some plugins that are no longer shown in the UI still have the plugin code to make them callable by legacy scripts (`plug-in-sharpen` for instance)

Comment: You mean "G" icon to the left of the name? But Deinterlace has the same icon and it's in the browser.

Comment: See augmented answer

Comment: Sad. I had big hopes about GIMP API to process lots of images.

Comment: The GEGL tools can be called in a shell script using the `gegl` command (at least on Linux). See also if by any chance what you want to do exists in the [GMIC plugin](http://gmic.eu/) (which can be called in Gimp scripts, but also in a shell).

Comment: There is tools -> GEGL operation, but no Noise reduction filter there, so even if, then what to call?
GMIC plugin indeed has JPEG smooth - close to what I needed. I suppose I have to run `plug-in-gmic-qt` with some command from my script.

Comment: https://zonderr.wordpress.com/2010/09/18/gmic-from-the-gimp-plugin-to-the-command-line/ - should be useful. Just need time to install on Lin, cause now I'm on win and have no Idea how to see terminal output here.